# Getting some syntax error while mapping-reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux

is this the right way to map the function inside the render

Here is my rendring code.

```
render() {
const { boardList } = { ...this.props.storyboardList };
const widgetListData = [...this.props.storyboardList.boardList].map(x => x.widgetList);
widgetListData.map((widgetresult, i) => {

return (

 <div className="clearfix">
   {this.state.isHidden ? (
  <div className="widget-list-wrapper clearfix">
    {this.state.widgetsList.length >= 0 ? (
   <div>
   <section className="section-break">
     {this.renderWidgets(widgetresult)}
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    )
    }
    }
```

Comment: Better show us code how you're storing the data. Show the code on how a new boards is getting created.

Comment: @sarneeh ..but its a huge code 3different component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since you are only using the state for render purposes only, you don't need to clone it using spread syntax. Cloning is needed when you want to modify the state,

Second, you are not returning anything from within render

Third, your syntaxes are not correct, since you are not properly closing tags or returning null from conditional render.

```
render() {
     const { boardList } = this.props.storyboardList;
     const widgetListData = boardList.map(x => x.widgetList);
     // note the return statement here
     return (
       <div>
       {widgetListData.map((widgetresult, i) => {
          return (
               <div className="clearfix">
                   {this.state.isHidden ? (
                      <div className="widget-list-wrapper clearfix">
                          {this.state.widgetsList.length >= 0 ? (
                               <div>
                                  <section className="section-break">
                                     {this.renderWidgets(widgetresult)}
                                  </section>
                                </div>
                           ) : null}
                      </div>
                   ): null}
              </div>
          )
    })}
    </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: error:A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Comment: @JMR, if you are using a react version < 16, you will need to wrap `widgetListData.map(` in a div,

Comment: "react": "15.6.1",

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Comment: i am getting anothe issue the board which i am adding getting added as many times i adding widget

Comment: whole page is getting added and new board i creating contains board widget

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170665/discussion-between-jmr-and-shubham-khatri).

Answer (score 2):

This is saving over itself. You don't need to convert it into an object.

```
let widgetresult = {}; 
for (let i = 0; i < widgetListData.length; i++) { 
    widgetresult = widgetListData[i]; 
}
```

You need to use the array and map over when creating your widgets:

```
var widgets = widgetListData.map((widgetresult, i) => {
    //then call your widget builder below
    renderWidgets(widgetresult);
}
```

In you render

```
{widgets}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response,what is call you widget builder here??can you please elobrate

Comment: I am referring to your function renderWidgets() Remove the mapping from your function and use map how I have shown you in my answer

Comment: i did that no changes , can you please update on that code.

Comment: i have changed ,can you please check, n say if its right way

Comment: You need to map into a variable and then display the variable. I'll update my answer.